# Packing data in .apk and unpacking it on installation

Tags: android, offline, osmdroid

I'm developing app on android and it must have offline maps. I'm using OSMDroid and created atlas with MOBAC. It's all OK, but I dont know, how to unpack atlas during the instalation. Can You suggest me how can I pack all tiles in .apk and unpack them on install on sdcard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include them in your res/raw folder.  At runtime, you can access them with

```
InputStream stream = context.getAssets().open("filename");
```

and save it out to the sdcard.

Comment: Great! Can You kindly help me to copy whole folder with it? (any other method, not only file by file)

ADDED: found answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447477/android-how-to-copy-files-in-assets-to-sdcard

THX!